# Retrieving unique names and based on that fetching the dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have two stored procedures like below:

```
Select distinct TempName from History_Table 

Select TempName,RunDate from History_Table  where TempName=@tempname
```

How do I use a single stored procedure to get a result set of distinct `tempname`'s and their associated `RunDate`?

```
  TempName     RunDate                       RunBy

1   test    2012-10-11 00:00:00.000 chandu
2   testing 2012-12-15 00:00:00.000 kumar
3   asdsad  2012-08-09 00:00:00.000 asdsad
4   test    2012-12-12 00:00:00.000 asdasds
15  test    2012-10-01 00:00:00.000 asdaddf
15  test    2012-09-12 00:00:00.000 bghgh

I have to display like

TempName   RunDate                   RunBy
test       dates(in a dropdown)      lastrun name(i.e asdasds)
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "but i want to do this in the one store proc". Do you wish to return all distinct Tempnames and their associated RunDates?

Comment: Yes exactly that is what i want

Comment: So you will not then be using @tempname variable...?

Comment: I have to use it because i am sending name as a parameter from front end for fetching the dates.

Comment: I don't under stand real problem but this query work for you.`Select distinct TempName,RunDate  from History_Table`.

Comment: you can even achieve by sub-query or group by clause..

Comment: @Shree I have tried what you have said but i am not getting unique names.

Comment: Can you give some sample data and expected results?

Answer (score 1):

From the comments you could try something like (SQL Server 2005 + [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.90%29.aspx))

```
;WITH UNames AS (
        Select  distinct 
                TempName 
        from    History_Table 
)
Select  ht.TempName,
        ht.RunDate 
from    History_Table  ht INNER JOIN
        UNames u    ON  ht.TempName = u.TempName
```

Comment: Can i use this as stored procedure??

Comment: You can use it **IN** a stored procedure.

Comment: But when i run this i am getting duplicate names.

Comment: There might be more than one RunDate per unique name. Explain a little more what your requirement is. Do you wish to have 2 data tables returned from the stored procedure? Or unique names and lets say MAX RunDates?

Comment: There are one RunDate per Duplicate name so i have to get a unique name and all the associated dates with it.No i cant use MAX RunDates

Answer (score 0):

Result sets from SQL have to follow a simple, tabular shape. There's no simple way to get a result where there's one row, of which one column contains multiple values (there are some ugly hacks, I won't go into).

The cleanest way to do this, so far as I'm concerned, is to run the following query:

```
Select TempName,RunDate,RunBy from History_Table ORDER BY TempName,RunDate
```

Then, in whatever is *consuming* the results from this table, it should keep track of the last `TempName` value it processed. If the current row has the *same* `TempName` value, then it should add `RunDate` to the existing drop-down. Otherwise, it should create a new row for the new `TempName` and create a drop-down with exactly one `RunDate` value.

Comment: But i need to get the TempName as unique thats why i am using two stored proc for this.

Comment: @Newbie - but as I explained, you can't have a single row with a column that contains multiple values (the `RunDate`s) - so what I'm proposing is that you return *multiple* rows, and process it on the consuming side so that you *display* a single row for each `TempName` value. That's why I've added the `ORDER BY` so that all rows relating to a single `TempName` appear together.